# Chrome Dev Tools VS Shopify Formatted Files

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, shopify, code-coverage, devtools

I am currently using Coverage from Chrome Dev Tools in order to remove unused CSS from my files. My issue is that the file from Coverage is completely different from the one in my theme editor. I posted two photos with my colorize.scss file. Does anyone know how can I see or edit the formatted file that the Dev Tools is showing me?

[Screenshot from Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qaj90.png)

[Screenshot from Shopify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdzdF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to `SCSS` files, Shopify theme contains files with extension `.scss.liquid` or `.css.liquid` and these files are compiled server-side and send as normal `CSS`.

So when you check it from the Dev tools or view page source these are compiled versions and not contained `SCSS` code same as theme files.

**Note:** Shopify now withdraw the support to the `SCSS` file with respect to better page load speed, but there is backward compatibility for the past old theme that have these `SCSS` files.